# Change Excel Column Labels in C# (Interop.Excel)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

Im trying to create and open a new Excel File on a ButtonClick event without saving it.

Code is working properly, but i need to change the Column labels (not the first row) of the first 10 Columns from A, B, C, D.. to Country1, Country2, Country3..

I cant find an example on the web, can you help me?

This is the Code that i wrote, it creates an Excel and Open it when someone calls the ButtonClick event:

```
private void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            ExcelApp.Application excelApp = new ExcelApp.Application();
            ExcelApp.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
            ExcelApp.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
            excelWorkSheet.Name = "Travel";
            excelApp.Visible = true;}
```

Comment: record macro when you do it manually and then check the source ....

Comment: The Excel file is a new file, im trying to create a Template Example when someone press that Button, without saving it
@Selvin can u explain in an easier way?

Comment: it was irony ... you can't do this even manually (or you are talking about named ranges - then seriously recording macro should help)

Comment: @Selvin Sorry but programming isnt my world, i work in an IT department and i do C# programs just to automate some jobs of employees.
No i need to Show the Excel with Column Labels edit as i want, so its impossible?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know thats not possible because Excel is also working internally with those column declarations.

All you can do is insert some sort of header row in the first row or where you want to have it and you this one...